# login info sql windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

im using windows authentication and standard username to access my database in mssql

what password do i need to put it to connect to database via linq or do i leave pwd blank.

I have tried to create account in the management studio this dint work either

Comment: If your using windows authentication, the password will automatically be given by windows.

Comment: I have this as my code and im still getting the error login failed
("server = LAPTOP-RED\\SQLEXPRESS; uid = Laptop-Red\\User;  database = youthpodcast");

Comment: you use the `InititalCatalog` and not the `database`

Comment: What you mean is i do this then  ("server = LAPTOP-RED\\SQLEXPRESS; uid = Laptop-Red\\User; inititalCatalog = youthpodcast")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you use the connection string like this:

Data Source=YOURSERVER;Initial Catalog=Nodthwind;Integrated Security=true;

where Integrated Security=true says that the application will try to access the server using the windows account under which it runs. So you don't have to provide any passwords.

Comment: when i add this connection string then what do i need to do in my c# code to call the connectionstring i have this at the moment.

 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("server = LAPTOP-RED\\SQLEXPRESS; uid = Laptop-Red\\User;  database = youthpodcast");

Comment: You don't "call" a connection string. You use the class which uses the connection string. In your case you access the methods of the SqlConnection object you created (or pass it as a parameter to other objects which use the connection). And then you create commands, etc.

I suggest you read a bit about ADO.NET or Linq to sql or Entity Framework. These are all database access technologies.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Authentication, you can use of the following type of connectionstring.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=TITAN\SQLEXPRESS;Initial
     Catalog=SportsStore;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=adam;Password=adam"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```